# Align items in itemize despite the diffrence

Tags: indentation, itemize

How can I align the two items in this case:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{theorem} 
    here is my theorem.
        \begin{itemize} 
            \item[(a)-(f)] Same as Conditions (a)-(f) of Lamma 1.
            \item[(g)]  a new Condition.
         \end{itemize}
    \end{theorem} 
     \end{document}
```

In the current case, (a) in the first item is not aligned with the (g) in the second item. I would also like that the items appear inside the theorem and not with the same indent as the theorem.

Comment: How about using a `tabular`?

Answer (score 2):

If it is only for a particular case, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item[(a)-(f)] Same as Conditions (a)-(f) of Lamma 1.
    \item[(g)\phantom{-(f)}]  a new Condition.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

or this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize} 
    \item[\hbox to 1cm{(a)-(f)}] Same as Conditions (a)-(f) of Lamma 1.
    \item[\hbox to 1cm{(g)}]  a new Condition.
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Try this for the edited question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,enumitem}%%added enumitem
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} 
here is my theorem.
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=.5in]
        \item[\hbox to 1cm{(a)-(f)}] Same as Conditions (a)-(f) of Lamma 1.
        \item[\hbox to 1cm{(g)}]  a new Condition.
     \end{itemize}
\end{theorem} 
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I edited the question.

Comment: Added another solution for your edited question.

Comment: thanks, but I am using IEEEtran style and apparently enumitem is already redefined in that, so  I can not compile when I add the package enumitem.

Comment: Try without adding the package ;)

Comment: @yes, I tried without adding teh package and it gives the same shape as your two previous solutions !